# PDO::fetch is slow when returning ids from INSERT statement

Tags: php, postgresql, performance, pdo

I'm using PHP version 7+ (tried on 7.0, 7.1,7.2) and PostgreSQL version 11 (tried also on version 10). And I'm having trouble with PDO::fetch (or fetchAll) methods when executing SQL query like:

```
INSERT INTO test_product_table (name, default_image_id, created_at)
VALUES (:p1, :p2, :p3),(:p4, :p5, :p6),(:p7, :p8, :p9)
RETURNING id
```

with basic PHP code like:

```
/** @var string $sql - query above **/
/** @var array $params - parameters **/
/** @var PDO $databaseConnection - PostgreSQL PDO connection**/


$res = $databaseConnection->prepare($sql);
$res->execute($params);

$res->fetchAll(); //or $res->fetch() in loop
```

I don't think it really matters, but there is DDL of the test table:

```
create table test_product_table
(
    id               serial                   not null
        constraint test_product_table_pkey
            primary key,
    name             text                     not null,
    default_image_id integer,
    created_at       timestamp with time zone not null
);
```

**I need to insert a lot of data (like thousands of rows and more) and then retrieve inserted IDs** and assign them to objects in PHP. But the time spends on fetching is extreme. I tried to do this without parameters - using the quote method - and the query is quick, but I don't really want to make an ultra-long string query with quoted parameters. But for 5000 rows it took, for example, 900ms with parameter query and 150ms with the quoted query.

So basically - **the problem is slow fetching returned IDs from insert query, that uses parameters**.

Can anyone explain to me why is the fetching so slow when using parameters instead of the quote? And is there some workaround?